# RcppArmadillo expmat hangs for a 4x4 matrix

Tags: c++, r, matrix, rcpp, armadillo

I have a pathological 4x4 matrix that makes the `expmat` function in Armadillo hang. The pathological matrix is:

```
a<-matrix(c(-2.5654e+060,4.6979e-018,2.5654e+060,7.2765e-035
            ,2.8913e+000, -3.6633e+001,3.3731e+001,1.0003e-002
            ,1.0656e-009,1.9037e-002, -1.9732e-001,1.7828e-001
            , 0e+000, 0e+000, 0e+000, 0e+000), nrow=4, byrow=T)
```

The .cpp file looks like this:

```
# include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
mat exp_mat(mat x) {
  return(expmat(x));
}
```

Feed the pathological matrix to this function would make it hang with a message:

```
warning: solve(): system seems singular; attempting approx solution
```

I know that this matrix is badly conditioned, but the `expm` function in R package "expm" can deal with it with no problem using its default algorithm. Is there anyway to get around this problem in RcppArmadillo? At least I want to avoid the hanging by dealing with the warning message.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27591868/armadillo-c-expmat-stacks), but I don't consider my question to be a duplicate since I just updated both Rcpp and RcppArmadillo right before posting. The problem in that other thread is supposed to have been fixed by Armadillo, so it seems there is something else going on here.

Comment: updating rcpparmadillo is not equivalent to updating armadillo, which contains the actual algorithm.

Comment: which version of *armadillo* are you using?

Comment: How can I check the version of armadillo? I can only see that the version of RcppArmadillo in R is 0.7.100.3.0.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: That is not as stated as each RcppArmadillo release tends to shadow the corresponding Armadillo release---our 0.7.100.3.* are based on Conrad's 7.100.3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Quick Observations

Few notes:

1. The `expmat()` algorithm offered in the [`expm` package](https://github.com/cran/expm/tree/master/src) is different from the `arma::expmat()` algorithm.
2. Supposedly, from the linked post, this was fixed in 4.550.4. The change seems to have been include as the file source (#3) is the same with the `armadillo` source even though `RcppArmadillo` seems to have skipped the point release e.g.[4.550.0 and 4.550.1 were merged in](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/c85985e243efb3179beafe9f309597758659bb3c/debian/changelog#L146-L158).
3. The actual implementation shipped (at the time of writing) is [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/6450efdb9b727539dabd13467db5a7a0f25c8b38/inst/include/armadillo_bits/op_expmat_meat.hpp#L49-L91) and it definitely looks like the `unsigned int` [issue raised on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27636629/1345455) has been fixed.

## Debugging the `arma::expmat()` command

With this being said, let's take a quick peek behind the scenes with a few debug statements. **Note:** I've opted to select `T` as a `double` per the API docs.

Onto the short debug program:

```
# include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void run_exp_mat_routine(const arma::mat& x) {

  const double norm_val = norm(x, "inf");

  Rcpp::Rcout << "norm:" << norm_val << std::endl;

  Rcpp::Rcout << "Value of T(0):" << (double(0)) << std::endl;
  Rcpp::Rcout << "Inequality:" << (norm_val > double(0)) << std::endl;

  Rcpp::Rcout << "log2: " << std::log2(norm_val) << std::endl;

  int exponent = int(0); std::frexp(std::log2(norm_val), &exponent);

  Rcpp::Rcout << "exponent: " << exponent << std::endl;

  const arma::uword s = arma::uword( (std::max)(int(0), exponent + int(1)) );

  Rcpp::Rcout << "s: " << s << std::endl;

  const arma::mat AA = x / std::pow(2.0,s);

  Rcpp::Rcout << "AA: " <<  std::endl << AA << std::endl;

  double c = 0.5;

  arma::mat E(AA.n_rows, AA.n_rows, arma::fill::eye);  
  Rcpp::Rcout << "Init E:" << std::endl << E << std::endl; 

  E += c * AA;

  Rcpp::Rcout << "Mod E:" << std::endl <<  E << std::endl; 

  arma::mat D(AA.n_rows, AA.n_rows, arma::fill::eye); 

  Rcpp::Rcout << "Init D:" << std::endl << D << std::endl; 

  D -= c * AA;

  Rcpp::Rcout << "Mod D:" << std::endl <<  D << std::endl; 

  arma::mat X = AA;

  bool positive = true;

  const arma::uword N = 6;

  for(arma::uword i = 2; i<=N; ++i){
    c = c * double(N - i + 1) / double(i * (2*N - i + 1));

    X = AA * X;

    E += c * X;

    if(positive)  { D += c * X; }  else  { D -= c * X; }

    positive = (positive) ? false : true;

    Rcpp::Rcout << "Loop: " << i << ", c: " << c << ", positive:" << positive << std::endl;

    Rcpp::Rcout << "X: " << std::endl << X << std::endl << "E: " << std::endl << E << std::endl;
  }

  //arma::mat out = solve(D,E);

  // Rcpp::Rcout << "out:" << std::endl << out << std::endl;
  // 
  // for(arma::uword i = 0; i < s; ++i){
  //   out = out*out;
  // }


  // Rcpp::Rcout << "out: " << out <<std::endl;
}

/*** R

   a <- matrix(c(-2.5654e+060,4.6979e-018,2.5654e+060,7.2765e-035
    ,2.8913e+000, -3.6633e+001,3.3731e+001,1.0003e-002
   ,1.0656e-009,1.9037e-002, -1.9732e-001,1.7828e-001
   , 0e+000, 0e+000, 0e+000, 0e+000), nrow=4, byrow=T)


   run_exp_mat_routine(a)

 */
```

### Debug Results

The results are broken into the initialization phase and then the looping phase where the issue resides.

```
norm: 5.1308e+60
Value of double(0): 0
Inequality: 1
log2: 201.675
exponent: 8
s: 9
AA: 
  -5.0105e+57   9.1756e-21   5.0105e+57   1.4212e-37
   5.6471e-03  -7.1549e-02   6.5881e-02   1.9537e-05
   2.0812e-12   3.7182e-05  -3.8539e-04   3.4820e-04
            0            0            0            0

Init E:
   1.0000        0        0        0
        0   1.0000        0        0
        0        0   1.0000        0
        0        0        0   1.0000

Mod E:
  -2.5053e+57   4.5878e-21   2.5053e+57   7.1060e-38
   2.8235e-03   9.6423e-01   3.2940e-02   9.7686e-06
   1.0406e-12   1.8591e-05   9.9981e-01   1.7410e-04
            0            0            0   1.0000e+00

Init D:
   1.0000        0        0        0
        0   1.0000        0        0
        0        0   1.0000        0
        0        0        0   1.0000

Mod D:
   2.5053e+57  -4.5878e-21  -2.5053e+57  -7.1060e-38
  -2.8235e-03   1.0358e+00  -3.2940e-02  -9.7686e-06
  -1.0406e-12  -1.8591e-05   1.0002e+00  -1.7410e-04
            0            0            0   1.0000e+00
```

Now the looping part seems to trigger the error in the last iteration (e.g. `i = 6`) because the number becomes too large to represent within a double structure.

```
Loop: 2, c: 0.113636, positive:0
X: 
  2.5106e+115   1.8630e+53 -2.5106e+115   1.7447e+54
  -2.8295e+55   5.1217e-03   2.8295e+55   2.1542e-05
  -1.0428e+46  -2.6746e-06   1.0428e+46  -1.3347e-07
            0            0            0            0

E: 
  2.8529e+114   2.1170e+52 -2.8529e+114   1.9826e+53
  -3.2153e+54   9.6481e-01   3.2153e+54   1.2217e-05
  -1.1850e+45   1.8287e-05   1.1850e+45   1.7409e-04
            0            0            0   1.0000e+00

Loop: 3, c: 0.0151515, positive:1
X: 
 -1.2579e+173 -9.3347e+110  1.2579e+173 -8.7418e+111
  1.4177e+113   1.0521e+51 -1.4177e+113   9.8524e+51
  5.2251e+103   3.8774e+41 -5.2251e+103   3.6311e+42
            0            0            0            0

E: 
 -1.9059e+171 -1.4143e+109  1.9059e+171 -1.3245e+110
  2.1481e+111   1.5940e+49 -2.1481e+111   1.4928e+50
  7.9168e+101   5.8748e+39 -7.9168e+101   5.5017e+40
            0            0            0   1.0000e+00

Loop: 4, c: 0.00126263, positive:0
X: 
  6.3029e+230  4.6772e+168 -6.3029e+230  4.3801e+169
 -7.1036e+170 -5.2714e+108  7.1036e+170 -4.9366e+109
 -2.6181e+161  -1.9428e+99  2.6181e+161 -1.8194e+100
            0            0            0            0

E: 
  7.9582e+227  5.9055e+165 -7.9582e+227  5.5305e+166
 -8.9692e+167 -6.6557e+105  8.9692e+167 -6.2331e+106
 -3.3056e+158  -2.4530e+96  3.3056e+158  -2.2972e+97
            0            0            0   1.0000e+00

Loop: 5, c: 6.31313e-05, positive:1
X: 
 -3.1581e+288 -2.3435e+226  3.1581e+288 -2.1947e+227
  3.5593e+228  2.6412e+166 -3.5593e+228  2.4735e+167
  1.3118e+219  9.7344e+156 -1.3118e+219  9.1162e+157
            0            0            0            0

E: 
 -1.9937e+284 -1.4795e+222  1.9937e+284 -1.3855e+223
  2.2470e+224  1.6674e+162 -2.2470e+224  1.5616e+163
  8.2815e+214  6.1454e+152 -8.2815e+214  5.7552e+153
            0            0            0   1.0000e+00

Loop: 6, c: 1.50313e-06, positive:0
X: 
          inf  1.1742e+284         -inf  1.0997e+285
 -1.7834e+286 -1.3234e+224  1.7834e+286 -1.2394e+225
 -6.5728e+276 -4.8775e+214  6.5728e+276 -4.5677e+215
            0            0            0            0

E: 
          inf  1.7650e+278         -inf  1.6529e+279
 -2.6807e+280 -1.9892e+218  2.6807e+280 -1.8629e+219
 -9.8797e+270 -7.3314e+208  9.8797e+270 -6.8658e+209
            0            0            0   1.0000e+00
```

Thus, the infinity symbol is passed to the solve parameter, which would break the program.

Outside of running a separate function to check if the matrix is infinite, I'm not sure there is another way since the algorithm seems sound compared to http://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/researchpdf/19ways+.pdf . Though, I'll let more experienced folk comment on that regard.

**Edit**

## Validating output in R with *expm::expm(a)*

Quick example of the routine in R:

```
# install.packages("expm")
library("expm")

a <- matrix(c(-2.5654e+060,4.6979e-018,2.5654e+060,7.2765e-035
              ,2.8913e+000, -3.6633e+001,3.3731e+001,1.0003e-002
              ,1.0656e-009,1.9037e-002, -1.9732e-001,1.7828e-001
              , 0e+000, 0e+000, 0e+000, 0e+000), nrow=4, byrow=T)
```

Results:

```
             [,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 2.403680e-62 0.02132743  1.369318 0.1998306
[2,] 1.543272e-60 1.36931834 41.028506 3.4698436
[3,] 2.403680e-62 0.02132743  1.369318 0.1998306
[4,] 0.000000e+00 0.00000000  0.000000 1.0000000
```

## Validating output *MATLAB*

Since this function should provide similar output to *MATLAB* (according to the author in the linked post) let's do quick run.

```
A = [-2.5654e+060,4.6979e-018,2.5654e+060,7.2765e-035;
      2.8913e+000, -3.6633e+001,3.3731e+001,1.0003e-002;
      1.0656e-009,1.9037e-002, -1.9732e-001,1.7828e-001;
      0e+000, 0e+000, 0e+000, 0e+000]
```

The representation of `A` in *MATLAB* is:
    A =

```
   1.0e+60 *

   -2.5654    0.0000    2.5654    0.0000
    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000
         0         0         0         0
```

To obtain the exponential matrix (not exponential by element), we use *MATLAB*'s [`expm(A)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/expm.html):

```
ans =

    0.0000    0.0213    1.3693    0.1998
    0.0000    1.3693   41.0285    3.4698
    0.0000    0.0213    1.3693    0.1998
         0         0         0    1.0000
```

## Bottom Line

So, the *R* and *MATLAB* version agree. Thus, the implementation chosen for the matrix decomposition in *armadillo* might not be ideal.

Comment: Thanks for all the details.  Do we conclude it is basically another 'floating point math' and finite precision issue?

Comment: I think the error in this case is definitely related to floating point issues due to the `inf` representation being obtained. However, I think it is also based in the exponential matrix algorithm used in *armadillo* being subpar when compared to *MATLAB* or *R*'s equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed debugging. Is there any way to "catch" this before the algorithm goes into an infinite loop beside hacking the source code of `expmat`? The warning thrown out by `expmat` in this case is not a runtime error so I can't intercept it with `try catch`. Or can I?

Comment: No real way to handle this without customizing your own function and checking for finite matrix entries. You may want to look into potentially porting over the algorithm used in `expm`.

Comment: Or just use `expm` from R.  It exports the function; I use that in RcppKalman (one of my GitHub repos, not on CRAN); there are unit tests for it as well.

Comment: Per an email thread, the next version of Armadillo provides a failure flag that should indicate if the 'expmat' will fail due to its conditioning

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel: is there any way to use an R function such as `expm` inside c++ code? In my situation, matrix exponential is an intermediate step in a fairly complex loop already written in C++.

Comment: This feature is now patched into armadillo in v7.200

Comment: Grab a copy of the new feature in the GitHub only release of `RcppArmadillo` v7.200.1 via: `devtools::install_github("rcppcore/rcpparmadillo")` @aenima

Comment: @Coatless: Grabbed it and it works now with a proper error message that can be intercepted by `tryCatch`. Thanks! And also thanks to the devs for such a fast patch!